# What model should I use for taking String value as input dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm making an anti-scam bot and I want to predict if a message is a scam message, but it throws a ValueError(could'nt convert string to float)
I am currently using the Decision Tree algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all the models accept floats and don't accept Strings, you have multiple ways to convert String to numbers (preprocess your data) before feeding it to your model as input.

You can try for example Word2Vec model by Gensim:
[Word2Vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html)

Comment: How would I do such a thing?

Comment: You can try Word2Vec by Gensim, easy to use, works well usually, and has a lot of examples.